# How to cancel on going transaction(in controller) from UI in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, transactions, controller, cancellationtokensource

[image]

I am sending Transaction request from UI to controller and processing that request in controller.

This process may consume time around 10 seconds.

While processing transaction the user has a provision to cancel the transaction.

**So i need to check whether cancel button has been clicked before every commit.**

I Suspect when cancel button clicked I cannot pass that value as new request since new instance of controller will be created.

Another option is using `static`.But suggestions tell me that don't introduce static fields for controllers.

How to handle this situation? (may be with some token or still some easy work around is there ?)

Comment: Lovely design but where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what specific UI you are using, but what you can do is terminate the request by clicking the cancel button.

If you are in javascript you can just call abort (content take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery))

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Then in the MVC code just bind the cancellation token and check it before calling submit (or better yet use async APIs and pass in the cancellation token).

```
public ActionResult Action(string param, CancellationToken token)
{
     // do your thing

     if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
         // abort
     }

     // do your thing
}
```